# Why is apache installing when PHP module included?

Tags: debian, puppet

I am using Debian 7.x

This is such odd behavior

1. I am invoking puppet through vagrant provisioner
2. I am using puppetlabs/debian-7.8-64-puppet as the base image

Why is Apache loading even though there is no reference to apache anywhere in my puppet script?

Here is the entire puppet script:

```
#
# Install all required packages
#

$packages = [
    "curl",

    "nginx",

    #"php5-gd",        
    #"php5-cli", 
    "php5-fpm", 
    "php5-ldap",
    #"php5-mysql",

    "mysql-server",

    "htmldoc",
]

package { $packages:
    ensure => present,
}

#
# Configure PHP-FPM
#

service { "php5-fpm":
    ensure => running,
    require => Package['php5-fpm'],
}

#
# Configure NGINX
#

service { "nginx":
  require => Package["nginx"],
  ensure => running,
  enable => true
}

file { "/etc/nginx/sites-available/default":
  ensure => "file",
  require => Package["nginx"],
  content => file("/var/www/.vagrant/puppet/modules/nginx/files/aerospace"),
}

file_line { "Append required Cadorath Aerospace NGINX parameters":
  require => Package["nginx"],
  path => "/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params",
  line => file("/var/www/.vagrant/puppet/modules/nginx/files/params.conf"),
}
```

Whenever I uncomment php5-gd or php5-mysql - Apache is somehow magically loaded and takes precedence over NGINX???

I literally will uncomment that line - rebuild machine SSH and run a ps -aux and suddenly I see Apache not NGINX serving my pages

Ideas?

Comment: Debian's PHP5 package requires *one* of `libapache2-mod-php5`, `libapache2-mod-php5filter`, `php5-cgi` or `php5-fpm`. https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/php5 I'm not hugely familiar with Puppet, but would moving the `php5-fpm` up after `nginx` get it to install before the other PHP packages?

Comment: Negative. I don't understand WTF puppet is doing. I moved nginx to the top of the packages list bottom and everywhere in between and Apache still somehow gets installed over top if I require those php5-xxx packages :s

Comment: @ceejayoz: Puppet doesn't follow any implicit order you might try by listing things in a specific order. This is a very basic principle of it. Instead, if items depend on each other, you have to make this explicity, e.g. by `require` statements. So, in this case it might be necessary to have the service `pfp5-fpm` also to require `Package['nginx']` (or whatever is necessary to get the package dependencies right.

Comment: How do I prevent apache from installing tho? Or how do I install php5-mysql without bringing on Apache?

Comment: I think you'd want to make all the other PHP packages require `php5-fpm`. Once `php5-fpm` is installed, it won't try to install Apache anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order you specify for the packages in the `$packages` list is irrelevant, Puppet will create a number of `package` objects from it and execute them in an arbitrary order, with each object resulting in one call to `apt-get install`, which prevents `apt` to do its own dependency resolution with the full list of packages you want to install and might result in pulling in a default package to resolve problems (Apache in this case).

One way around this should work somewhat like the following:

```
$packages = [
    "curl",
 # "nginx",   ## Not nginx!
    "php5-gd",        
    "php5-cli", 
    "php5-fpm", 
    "mysql-server",
    "htmldoc",
]

package { 'nginx': 
  ensure => present,
}

package { $packages:
    ensure => present,
    require => Package['nginx'],
}
```

so you make sure that `nginx` is the first package installed (it might be necessary to do this for other or additional packages instead of nginx, depending on how the actual dependency tree works out.

Comment: You'll actually want to break out `php5-fpm`. Without `php5-fpm`, `php5-mysql`, `php5-gd`, and several others will default to installing Apache as their dependency.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you mean by break out fpm?